# I get an error when I wanna use React Navigation, Error: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I get an error when I wanna use React Navigation,
Error: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreen" was not found in the UIManger.

[This is my source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgacH.png)

Answer (score 1):

May you should install this package

```
npm i react-native-screens
```

And try to close the terminal and the app, and run it again `npm run android` or `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

Two days but i've managed to fix the problem by adding RNScreensPackage, SafeAreaContextPackage and RNGestureHandlerPackage to my react packages.

Be sure to install base packages:
`yarn install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-safe-area-context react-native-screens`

Build the Android folder on Android Studio and add the packages to your react native android entry.

The result looks like this:

```
// My packages list, 
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new RNScreensPackage(),
            new SafeAreaContextPackage(),
            new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
            new MainReactPackage() // this my app module
    );
}
```

and then use it on instance manager

```
mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setCurrentActivity(this)
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModulePath("index.android")
            .addPackages(getPackages()) // <-- Package list
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
```

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue but it gets resolved I don't know how!! what I did just close the cli when I see this error(RNSScreen). after this I follow the [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator/) and restarting my cli.

> **what I think is that issue with react native.**